# JNI UnsatisfiedLinkError: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am trying to call a function from c++ via JNI.
I have followed the instructions I found online and still get an Exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: \path\to\dll\remoteAPI.dll: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed

The path to the DLL file is correct and it is located there. 
I added the path via the VMOptions in IntelliJ via: **-Djava.library.path=\path\to\dll**

So why do I still get an Exception? Apparently this exception is throws when the DllMain returns the value false. But do I need one here or has the jni-library one and if I need to implement it, where do I put it?

**entities_remoteAPI.h**

```cpp
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class entities_remoteAPI */

#ifndef _Included_entities_remoteAPI
#define _Included_entities_remoteAPI
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     entities_remoteAPI
 * Method:    sayHello
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_entities_remoteAPI_sayHello
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

**entities_remoteAPI.cpp**

```cpp
#include <jni.h>
#include "entities_remoteAPI.h"


JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_entities_remoteAPI_sayHello
  (JNIEnv* env, jobject thisObject) {

}
```

**App.java**

```java
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );

        System.loadLibrary("remoteAPI");

        RemoteAPI ai = new RemoteAPI();
        ai.sayHello();
    }
}
```

**entities/RemoteAPI.java**

```java
package entities;

public class RemoteAPI {
    public native void sayHello();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I now got rid of the exception by compiling the dll from the command line instead of using the IDE **Code::Blocks**.
The commands I used where

> g++ -c -I%JAVA_HOME%\include -I%JAVA_HOME%\include\win32 entities_RemoteAPI.cpp -o entities_RemoteAPI.o

and

> g++ -shared -o remoteAPI.dll entities_RemoteAPI.o -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias

Apparently it has something to do with the options Code::Blocks passes when building the DLL.