# How to fix Java 15 JNI "UnsatisfiedLinkError: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed"

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have found other posts of people having this exact error, but not one thus far has had a solution that worked for me. For reference, here are the things I have found:

https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/2233828/jni-link-error-a-dynamic-link-library-dll-initialization-routine-failed

[JNI UnsatisfiedLinkError: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58113444/jni-unsatisfiedlinkerror-a-dynamic-link-library-dll-initialization-routine-fa)

https://www.debugcn.com/en/article/5175409.html

https://coderanch.com/t/132356/engineering/java-lang-UnsatisfiedLinkError

Either their solution was not relevant to my particular scenario, or it did not fix the issue for me.

Everything is being compiled on the command line with a Windows 10 computer and using GCC (gcc-5.1.0-tdm64-1-c++) for compiling the C++ portions into a .dll, and JDK 15.0.1's javac tool. There are three relevant files here, one being the header file derived from the java file.

Main.java:

```java
public class Main {
    static {
        System.load("C:\\Users\\17659\\Documents\\Programming\\C++ & Java - JNI Tests\\library.dll");
        //System.loadLibrary("library");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().outputText();
    }
    
    private native void outputText();
}
```

Main.h:

```cpp
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class Main */

#ifndef _Included_Main
#define _Included_Main
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     Main
 * Method:    outputText
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Main_outputText
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

Library.cpp:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Main.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Main_outputText(JNIEnv * a, jobject b)
{
    std::cout << "testing";
}
```

They are contained all within the folder with the absolute path of `C:\Users\17659\Documents\Programming\C++ & Java - JNI Tests`. With a command prompt set to that as the current directory, I run the following commands in order:

```
g++ -c -o Library.o -I"C:\Users\17659\Documents\jdk-15.0.1\include" -I"C:\Users\17659\Documents\jdk-15.0.1\include\win32" Library.cpp
g++ -shared -o library.dll Library.o
javac Main.java
java Main
```

Despite the multiple things I have tried, I *always* get this same error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\17659\Documents\Programming\C++ & Java - JNI Tests\library.dll: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:383)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:227)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:169)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2407)
        at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:747)
        at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1857)
        at Main.<clinit>(Main.java:3)
```

I have used `nm` on the resulting .dll to make sure the name of the function is correct, and it does seem to be exactly as it should.

The entire point of this little project of mine is to figure out how JNI works, since I have a plan to write a small portion of a program in C++. The rest of the program though would work best in Java (for me). I do not know what I need to do to get this program to work, I have spent approximately 2 hours of googling and fiddling attempting to get it to function. This is on a 64-bit OS. How can I make this program run and print out the very little amount of text I would like it to print out?

Update: As per [@JornVernee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3699139/jorn-vernee) removing the line `#include <iostream>` and replacing the `std::cout` with a `printf()` to write to the console did actually work. So my question now becomes this: why does including a standard C++ header cause an error?

Comment: AFAICS this message is reported directly by the Windows [LoadLibrary API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibrarya). To simplify debugging, you could write a small C++ program that tries to load the library using the same API, and see if you can reproduce the problem that way. Best guess is that there's a mismatch between the C++ std lib you're compiling against, and the one that is loaded when running the program (could try and remove the dependency)

Comment: Have you tried just using `system.load("library")` and then using `java -Djava.library.path=. Main`? The problem from the stack trace appears to be that the native library isn't being found by the JVM instance.

Comment: @Zoso I have indeed tried that method, I only got the same error, unfortunately. I feel certain that it isn't that the library isn't being found, as changing the name I have will change the error to indicate that it was not able to find the library.

Comment: @JornVernee Unfortunately, if I require a windows SDK for that test, I can't do that. The computers I am using to write this code do not allow me permission to install the SDK (in any way I was able to figure out). If you know a way to get the windows SDK w/o any sort of installation, and instead just a download and extraction or something similar, please do inform me. I was not able to figure it out.

Comment: @JornVernee So I did have a go at removing the dependency, and Java was able to run the program. I'm not too well-versed in how C++ operates so I am a bit uncertain of how to go about fixing this. I would *think* I should look into updating my version of GCC, so that's where I'll start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, [@JornVernee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3699139/jorn-vernee) effectively nailed the issue right on the head. It was a mismatch between the standard library I had for C++ and the one being loaded. I changed the version of GCC I was using to a more up-to-date version, recompiled the entire project, and the program works now.